# Access database by hibernate from multiple JVM instances

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, caching, hibernate-cache

My application is running in multiple JVM instances (in separate docker containers).

The application uses hibernate (and spring-data-jpa) to access the single database (MySQL) instance.

Do I need to disable some hibernate cache (e.g. the first-level-cache for a hibernate session) to get that setup work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate first level cache is enabled by default and there is no way to disable it.

But for second level cache you can use for example, Ehcache RMI Replicated Caching:
http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/replication/rmi-replicated-caching

It provides a good solution for caching in multiple JVM environment.

Comment: Thx. I really do not need a second level cache. Is the built-in first level cache prepared for a multiple JVM environment or do I need to replace it?

Comment: Yes it prepared for multiple JVM, you can use it